# Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` and a vector `x`:

`A` is a 50x30 matrix

`x` is a 1x30 vector

I want to multiply `A` by `x`, yet whenever I try `z = A * x` I get the error `Inner matrix dimensions must agree.` Yet surely with the same amount of columns the matrix dimensions do agree?

I'm confused as to why this works:

```
A = rand(2,2);
x = [1;2];
A * x
```

Yet this does not work:

```
A = rand(2,2);
x = 1:2;
A * x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transpose the second argument:

```
z = A * x.'
```

As the error suggest - **the inner matrix dimensions must agree** - you have 
`A = [50x30]` and `x = [1x30]`, the inner dimensions are **30** and **1**.

By tranposing you get `A = [50x30]` and `x = [30x1]`, the inner dimensions are then **30** and **30**, agreeing.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, x is 2 by 1. In the second example, x is 1 by 2.

Notice you are using ;(semi-colon) in first example and :(colon) in the second example. You may verify the dimensions by size(x) for both examples.

Answer (score 1):

In order to multiply `A` by a vector from the right the vector must be `30`-by-`1` and **not** `1`-by-`30` - this is the reason for the error you are getting.
To solve

```
z = A * x.';
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = [1;2];` creates a column vector `[1;2]`. In contrast, the command `x = 1:2;` creates a row vector `[1 2]`. Because of that, the matrix multiplication fails for the second example.