# multiply two arrays with different size in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to call a product of two arrays with different sizes but I get an error. This is the data:

```
A = [1 1 1 1;1 2 2 2;1 2 3 3;1 2 3 4];    
B = [-4 -7 -9 -10];    
X = [5 5 5 5];
```

I want to calculate this :

```
C = A*X+B
```

I have this error :

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Comment: Which matrices have different size? Do you mean "_not agreeing dimensions_"? Please check your dimensions. A calculation should be mathematically meaningful. Please try to understand what you are doing and to understand your error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner matrix dimensions must agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850858/inner-matrix-dimensions-must-agree)

Comment: size of matrice A is not like the size of B & X

Comment: Does it matter when calculating a product? Which dimensions should match when calculating a matrix product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose `X` and 'B' to get the correct result. Try the following:

```
C = A * (X.') + B.';
```